# Pythonically exporting digital certificate information from a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

It is possible to somehow 'pythonically' export a file's digital certificate's subject if the certificate itself is not installed on the workstation but is only used on that specific file?

I need to somehow extract that information from a file and check if it's correct. Preferably using Python/CMD/PowerShell

[image: What I need]

I'm currently using this python script (which I modified to run on Python 3.6): 
http://www.zedwood.com/article/python-openssl-x509-parse-certificate to parse a .cer file that I extract from the original executable file.

I extract the certificate with this little tool I've found (which I also modified to work with Python 3): 
https://blog.didierstevens.com/programs/disitool/ and afterwards I convert it from a DER-encoded binary to a base-64 with the Windows certutil.

The problem with the disitool script I use to extract the certificate from the file, though, is that it literally *cuts* the 'signature' bytearray from the executable itself using the pefile python module, which makes the extracted .cer file invalid, as per the python error that I keep getting when trying to load the certificate with the OpenSSL.crypto module:

```
 [('asn1 encoding routines', 'asn1_check_tlen', 'wrong tag'), ('asn1 encoding routines', 'asn1_item_embed_d2i', 'nested asn1 error'), ('asn1 encoding routines', 'asn1_template_noexp_d2i', 'nested asn1 error'), ('PEM routines', 'PEM_ASN1_read_bio', 'ASN1 lib')]
```

But parsing a good extracted certificate (with the first script I posted above) works, as you can see here:

[image: Parsing works just fine]]

TL:DR - I just need a way to export a certificate from a file, I guess. Also, if you've found my solution too complicated, if you have any idea how I could get that "Redmond" text from the certificate's Subject field, I'm **very** open to other ideas :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I bumped into this while searching for a similar solution. This is what worked for me. Part of the code is borrowed from `disitool.py`

```
import pefile
from OpenSSL import crypto
from OpenSSL.crypto import _lib, _ffi, X509


def get_certificates(self):
    certs = _ffi.NULL
    if self.type_is_signed():
        certs = self._pkcs7.d.sign.cert
    elif self.type_is_signedAndEnveloped():
        certs = self._pkcs7.d.signed_and_enveloped.cert

    pycerts = []
    for i in range(_lib.sk_X509_num(certs)):
        pycert = X509.__new__(X509)
        pycert._x509 = _lib.sk_X509_value(certs, i)
        pycerts.append(pycert)

    if not pycerts:
        return None
    return tuple(pycerts)


SignedFile = "/tmp/firefox.exe"

pe = pefile.PE(SignedFile)

address = pe.OPTIONAL_HEADER.DATA_DIRECTORY[
    pefile.DIRECTORY_ENTRY["IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_SECURITY"]
].VirtualAddress
size = pe.OPTIONAL_HEADER.DATA_DIRECTORY[
    pefile.DIRECTORY_ENTRY["IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_SECURITY"]
].Size

if address == 0:
    print("Error: source file not signed")
else:
    signature = pe.write()[address + 8 :]

    pkcs = crypto.load_pkcs7_data(crypto.FILETYPE_ASN1, bytes(signature))
    certs = get_certificates(pkcs)

    for cert in certs:
        c = crypto.dump_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert)
        a = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, c)
        # get data from parsed cert
        print(a.get_subject())
```

Comment: pip install pyOpenSSL

Answer (score 1):

You can get it done in a more concise way with the `cryptography` package:

```
import pefile
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import pkcs7

signedFile = "/tmp/firefox.exe"
pe = pefile.PE(signedFile)

address = pe.OPTIONAL_HEADER.DATA_DIRECTORY[pefile.DIRECTORY_ENTRY["IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_SECURITY"]].VirtualAddress
size = pe.OPTIONAL_HEADER.DATA_DIRECTORY[pefile.DIRECTORY_ENTRY["IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_SECURITY"]].Size

signature = pe.write()[address + 8 :]
certs = pkcs7.load_der_pkcs7_certificates(bytes(signature))

for cert in certs:
    print(a.subject.rfc4514_string())
```